# MinMaxScaler sklearn: should I normalize class labels too?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I am using MLPRegressor which takes 5 continuous features and 1 feature which draws values from a set of 40 values `[0,1,2,.., 39]`.

I was told that normalizing the features using `sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0,1))` can help with performance, both with MLP and LSTMs.

Thus I am using it on my `Xtrain` matrix containing the features above.

However, it looks weird to me that I should be minimizing also a categorical variable.. should I do it? The documentation says that (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) MInMaxScaler normalizes each feature separately. Should I take away the categorical column and normalize all the others?

Also, if it normalizes each feature separately, how does it know how to transform them back when I use `inverse_transform`?

Comment: If it's categorical, use [one-hot-encoding](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder).

Comment: The feature that is categorial is every half-hour of a day, (thus I actually have `48` classes), and they have correlations between them. Also, there is an order between them. This is not captured by the one-hot encoding

Comment: As for you first question, @sascha has given the answer. And about the `inverse_transform()`, MinMaxScaler will keep "per feature (column)" values for min, max, and scaling, which is used to get the original values back.

Comment: @VivekKumar thank you. However what if I just wanted to inverse_transform only one value. And this value was in two different features?

Comment: Can you explain more about this using an example. How will you transform one value?

Answer (score 3):

Categorical feature should be presented as OneHotEncoding. Still if you perform normalization of categorical feature, it will not harm your data. It just convert your data from one form to another form and keep the value discreteness.
Please find below small code example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, MinMaxScaler
data = np.array([-2,-2,-78,-78,-1,-1,0,0,1,1])
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
normalizedData = scaler.fit_transform(data.reshape(-1,1))
encoder = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto',sparse=False)
encodedData = encoder.fit_transform(normalizedData.reshape(-1,1))
print(encodedData)
```

O/P after OneHotEncoding:

```
[[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

And O/P will remain same even in case if I directly feed the data to encoder i.e. without normalizing.

Answer (score 2):

Categorical variables should be handled accordingly, i.e. with [one-hot encoding](https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/)

After that the MinMax scaler would not really change the encoded features.

Answering your last question - the scaler simply stores minima ans maxima for each input feacture separatley, so it can make inverse transform. And it makes sense to scale features independently - they may be of different scale AND even nature.

Answer (score 0):

Scaling categorical variables is unnecessary since there is no natural sense of Metric in these type of variables space.

The second answer - the MinMaxScaler object keeps `scale_, data_range_, data_min_ data_max_` after fitted to data(arrays in length of normalized variable).

This attributes enable the inverse transformation per each feature.